# Trying to scrape .md file into a csv

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a git .md file. I have made a python scraper but I'm kind of stuck on how to actually get the data I want. The page has a long list of job listings. they are all in separate Li elements. I want to get the A elements. After the A elements, there is just plain text separated by | I want to scrape those as well. I really want this to end up as a CSV file with the A tag as a column, the location text before the | as a column, and the remaining description text as a column.

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

def getLinkData(link):
    return requests.get(link).content

content = getLinkData('https://github.com/poteto/hiring-without-whiteboards/blob/master/README.md')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
ul = soup.find_all('ul')
li = soup.find_all("li")
data = []

for uls in ul:            
    rows = uls.find_all('a')   
    data.append(rows)    
 
print(data)
```

When I  run this I get the A tags, but obviously not the rest yet. There seem to be a few other ul elements that are included. I just want the one with all the job LIs but the LIs nor the UL have any ids or classes. Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I want? Maybe add Pandas into this(not sure how)

screenshot:
[image: target]

screenshot2:
[image]

Comment: can you screenshot your target?

Comment: do you mean screenshot the element inspector or the actual page data?

Comment: meant to screenshot the text you are looking for it.

Comment: ok posting now.

Comment: check posted answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/poteto/hiring-without-whiteboards/master/README.md'
res = requests.get(url).text
jobs = res.split('## A - C\n\n')[1].split('\n\n## Also see')[0]
jobs = [j[3:] for j in jobs.split('\n') if j.startswith('- [')]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Company', 'URL', 'Location', 'Info'])
for i, job in enumerate(jobs):
    company, rest = job.split(']', 1)
    url, rest = rest[1:].split(')', 1)
    rest = rest.split(' | ')
    if len(rest) == 3:
        _, location, info = rest
    else:
        _, location = rest
        info = np.NaN
    df.loc[i, :] = (company, url, location, info)
df.to_csv('file.csv')
print(df.head())
```

prints

| index | Company | URL | Location | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Able | https://able.co/careers | Lima, PE / Remote | Coding interview, Technical interview (Backlog Refinement + System Design), Leadership interview (Behavioural) |
| 1 | Abstract | https://angel.co/abstract/jobs | San Francisco, CA | NaN |
| 2 | Accenture | https://www.accenture.com/us-en/careers | San Francisco, CA / Los Angeles, CA / New York, NY / Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia | Technical phone discussion with architecture manager, followed by behavioral interview focusing on soft skills |
| 3 | Accredible | https://www.accredible.com/careers | Cambridge, UK / San Francisco, CA / Remote | Take home project, then a pair-programming and discussion onsite / Skype round. |
| 4 | Acko | https://acko.com | Mumbai, India | Phone interview, followed by a small take home problem. Finally a F2F or skype pair programming session |

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = list(chain.from_iterable([[(
        i['href'],
        i.get_text(strip=True),
        *(i.next_sibling[3:].split(' | ', 1) if i.next_sibling else ['']*2))
        for i in x.select('a')] for x in soup.select(
        'h2[dir=auto] + ul', limit=9)]))
    df = pd.DataFrame(goal)
    df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)


main('https://github.com/poteto/hiring-without-whiteboards/blob/master/README.md')
```